# Attached property bound to a list via converter

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm, attached-properties

I would like to extend some standard UIElements in my WPF. Ideally it would be a good solutiion to use attached properties. But I didn't managed to do it.

In my ViewModel I've a collection of custom objects:

```
        private ObservableCollection<ValidationFailure> validationFailures = new ObservableCollection<ValidationFailure>();
    public ObservableCollection<ValidationFailure> ValidationFailures
    {
        get { return validationFailures; }
        set
        {
            validationFailures = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => ValidationFailures);
        }
    }
```

This is what I'd like to bind to my Attached Property. In my view I also bind it as an ItemsSource of a ListBox. It shows the changes, and everything properly, that's why I think the collection notify well.

In my view I bind it with the following code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="ssn" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Margin="10,0,0,0"

                     Text="{Binding PatientAggRoot.Patient.Ssn}" 
                     Background="{Binding Path=CheckSsnButtonBackground}"

                     Validation:ValidationErrorAttached.HasValidationErrors="{Binding ValidationFailures,Converter={x:Static Converters:ConvertersHolder.ValidationErrorsLookupConverter},ConverterParameter='SSN',Mode=OneWay}" 
                                  />
```

My converter looks like these:

```
    public class ValidationErrorsLookupConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter implementation
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var validationLookup = (ObservableCollection<ValidationFailure>)value;
            bool hasErrors = validationLookup.Any(vf => vf.Key == ((string) parameter));
            return hasErrors;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Can't convert back");
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I tested the converter parameter, it's also working properly with the listbox;
Finally my attached property:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasValidationErrorsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HasValidationErrors",  typeof(Boolean), typeof(ValidationErrorAttached),  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true,      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnChangeCallBack, OnCoerceValueChanged));

    private static object OnCoerceValueChanged(DependencyObject d, object basevalue)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        return basevalue;
    }

    private static void OnChangeCallBack(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        if (((bool)e.NewValue))
        {
            ((TextBox) d).BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
        }
    }

    public static void SetHasValidationErrors(UIElement element, Boolean value)
    {
        element.SetValue(HasValidationErrorsProperty, value);
    }
    public static Boolean GetHasValidationErrors(UIElement element)
    {
        return (Boolean)element.GetValue(HasValidationErrorsProperty);
    }
```

It is in the ValidationErrorAttached class, which is a Freezable class.

When I open my form containing the textbox above, the Attached Property's coervalue is fired 2 times, change callback one times, but after when (the form is loaded) I change the collection in my VM, and based on the collection the converter change the return value, the attached property callbacks doesn't fire as I've expected. What did I wrong?

Comment: Do you have validation errors by default?

Comment: Generally there could be, but not in my test case: Shortly no. but the collection is not null, just empty.

Comment: That's like the problem them - does it pick up Collection.Add event?

Comment: I need to get used how to write comments, so again:

Get closer.
To clarify the scenario:
There are a validator in my VM, which runs if something changed on the view. Here is the relevant code:
    `          patientMainViewModel.ValidationFailures.Clear();
            int parse;
            if (!Int32.TryParse(patientMainViewModel.PatientAggRoot.Patient.Ssn, out parse))
            {
                patientMainViewModel.ValidationFailures.Add(new ValidationFailure("SSN", "Taj szám nem csak számokból áll"));
         }`
Now the problem is, that my converter also doesn't run. Do you have idea?

Comment: Try on your binding PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High just in your binding after Mode. Does it work? Gives it any errors? Does it show anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

You Observable collection has to be created as a DP. Beeing just a CLR property it's ain't capable of reporting about its Items Add/Remove events, it only reports about about the whole property sets.

Basically your CLR property should be no more than a wrapper for your ObservableCollection<..> Dependency property. Don't forget to initialise it either in the constrcutor or right from your DP declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The converter will run ONLY if your source property changes. This mean when the context's `PropertyChanged` event is raised for `ValidationFailures` property.

In your case you expect that to automatically happen for each `ValidationFailures.Add()`. Observable collection can notify collection changes and property changes for their own properties such as `Count`. But they will not autonotify the property that holds the collection as its value itself.

Either you have to raise `OnPropertyChanged("ValidationFailures")` after each `ValidationFailures.Add()` or change your logic to leverage the **observability** of the ValidationFailures i.e.e by handling collection changed event of the observable collection.

**Solution 1:**

I suggest that you create a function in your view model patientMainViewModel.

```
  void CheckAndValidate()
  {
        this.ValidationFailures.Clear();
        int parse;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(
              this.PatientAggRoot.Patient.Ssn, out parse))
        { 
             this.ValidationFailures.Add(
                    new ValidationFailure("SSN", "Taj szám nem csak számokból áll"));
             this.OnPropertyChanged("ValidationFailures");
        }
  }
```

**Solution 2**

Get rid of your converter and make your attached property to do all the bidding.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidationErrorsProperty
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ValidationErrors",
            typeof(ObservableCollection<ValidationFailure>),
            typeof(ValidationErrorAttached),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<ValidationFailure>(), OnChangeCallBack));

    private static void OnChangeCallBack(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var list = (ObservableCollection<ValidationFailure>)e.NewValue;
        if (list != null)
        {
            list.CollectionChanged +=
                delegate(
                    object sender,
                    System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs arg)
                    {
                        if (list.Count == 0)
                        {
                            ((TextBox) d).BorderBrush = null;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ((TextBox) d).BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                        }
                    };
        }
    }

    public static void SetValidationErrors(DependencyObject element, ObservableCollection<ValidationFailure> value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ValidationErrorsProperty, value);
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<ValidationFailure> GetValidationErrors(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<ValidationFailure>)element.GetValue(ValidationErrorsProperty);
    }
```

Let me know if you need any more help.